# Find the numbers of self-product within a range

Tags: algorithm, numbers, product, brute-force, factorization

The question is in the title. Now to make the term self-product more clear. Self-product means the product of the number and its digits. Example:

Self-Product(1234) = 1234*1*2*3*4 = 29616.

I've tried two methods.

**Brute-force**

Anyone's idea would be to check all combinations between 1 and N (upper bound of the range). And check if the number's self-product is within the range. This would be ideal for relativly low numbers, but having in mind that the range can be big as 10^20, it's becoming a problem, because it'll take a while before it prints the result.

**Factorization**

Another idea is to factorize the number within the range. If the range is between 60 000 and 70 000, when I check for 62 688, I'll get 62 688 as 2*2*2*2*2*3*653. Now knowing that 653 can't be a digit, that means that it have to be in the original number. Then again I have to combine all factors of 62 688 to get the right answer and it should output that this one is Self-Product of 2612, beacuse 62 688 = 2612 * 2 * 6 * 1 * 2.

In both situation I face a big problem, which is checking all of the combinations.

P.S I found that if number has n-digit then if it's self-product of some number than that number would have at least n/2 digits and no more than n. This would make the list of numbers that I will need to check a little bit smaller, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: And this is all supposed to be in in decimal representation?

Comment: No. You should output the number of self-product that are within the range.

Comment: so "1234" could be considered octal notation, too? Tricky ...

Comment: I don't understand your point, why should 1234 be in octal notaion?

Comment: You are assuming decimal. (and you assume everybody else does the same) Hint: this is also the clue to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Naming:**

```
sp(x) = Self-Product(x) = y
Range = a to b
```

**Notes:**

I'll assume you just want the count, but extending this to actually print all the numbers shouldn't be difficult.

The basic idea - Split the `x`'s up into having certain number prefixes and a certain number of digits and just determine whether some number of digits + prefix falls in the range, either completely (add number of possibilities, easy to calculate), partially (check longer prefix) or not at all (move along).

Note that any number `x` containing 0 is disallowed, since then `y` = 0.

The algorithm may have some inefficiencies, but it should provide a decent starting point. One improvement is that one should be able to do some binary-search-like process. Another is not recalculating the min/max all the time, since there's a certain amount of redundancy here.

**Notation:**
`min(c,d)` - minimum with c digits and a prefix of d (`min(c,)` means no prefix)
`max(c,d)` - maximum with c digits and a prefix of d
`range(c,d)` - Range from `min(c,d)` to `max(c,d)`

Note that `min(x,) = min(x,1) < min(x,2) < min(x,3) < ...` and
`max(x,) = max(x,9) > max(x,8) > max(x,7) > ...`

`min(c,d..e)` - set of minimums with c digits and any prefix from d to e
(between `min(c,d)` and `min(c,e)`)
`max(c,d..e)` - set of maximums with c digits and any prefix from d to e
(between `max(c,d)` and `max(c,e)`)

**Algorithm Through Example:**

I'll explain using an example for Range = 100 to 200.

```
// check 1 digit
min(1,): x = 1, y = 1*1 = 1 < 100
max(1,): x = 9, y = 9*9 = 81 < 100
  // not in range, nothing to do

// check 2 digits
min(2,): x = 11, y = 11*1*1 = 11 < 100
max(2,): x = 99, y = 99*9*9 = 8019 > 200
  // partially in range, check longer prefix
  min(2,1): x = 11, y = 11*1*1 = 11 < 100
  max(2,1): x = 19, y = 19*1*9 = 171 > 100
    // partially in range, check longer prefix
    sp(11..16) <= sp(16) = 96 < 100
    sp(17) = 119 // in range - increment count
    sp(18) = 144 // in range - increment count
    sp(19) = 171 // in range - increment count
  min(2,2): x = 21, y = 21*2*1 = 42 < 100
  max(2,2): x = 29, y = 29*2*9 = 522 > 200
    // partially in range, check longer prefix
    // others outside of range, omitted for brevity
    sp(23) = 138 // in range - increment count
    sp(24) = 192 // in range - increment count
  min(2,3): x = 31, y = 31*3*1 = 93 < 100
  max(2,3): x = 39, y = 39*3*9 = 1053 > 200
    // partially in range, check longer prefix
    // others outside of range, omitted for brevity
    sp(32) = 192 // in range - increment count
  min(2,4): x = 41, y = 41*4*1 = 164 < 200
  max(2,4): x = 49, y = 49*4*9 = 1764 > 200
    // partially in range, check longer prefix
    // others outside of range, omitted for brevity
    sp(41) = 164 // in range - increment count
  min(2,5): x = 51, y = 51*5*1 = 255 > 200
    // not in range, nothing to do
  // no need to process (2,6..9), since these are all > min(2,5) > 200

// check 3 digits
min(3,): x = 111, y = 111*1*1*1 = 111 < 200
max(3,): x = 999, y = 999*9*9*9 = 728271 > 200
  // partially in range, check longer prefix
  min(3,1): x = 111, y = 111*1*1*1 = 111 < 200
  max(3,1): x = 199, y = 199*1*9*9 = 16119 > 200
    // partially in range, check longer prefix
    min(3,11): x = 111, y = 111*1*1*1 = 111 < 200
    max(3,11): x = 119, y = 119*1*1*9 = 1071 > 200
      // partially in range, check longer prefix
      // others outside of range, omitted for brevity
      sp(111) = 111 // in range - increment count
    min(3,12): x = 121, y = 121*1*2*1 = 242 > 200
      // not in range, nothing to do
    // no need to process (3,13..19), since these are all > min(3,12) > 200
  min(3,2): x = 211, y = 211*2*1*1 = 411 > 200
    // not in range, nothing to do
  // no need to process (3,3..9), since these are all > min(3,2) > 200

// check 4 digits
min(4,): x = 1111, y = 1111*1*1*1 = 1111 > 200
  // not in range, nothing to do
// no need to check more digits, since min(n,) > min(n-1,) and min(4,) > 200
```

So the total count is 8 self-products that results in the range 100 to 200.

Notice that sometimes I check the start of the range, and sometimes the end. This is just to show what condition is important in that specific case.

Just to illustrate something, if the range were to have been 1-200, the range for 2 digits numbers with prefix 1 would be [11,171] as above, and 1 <= 11 <= 171 <= 200, so we can just include all 2 digits numbers with prefix 1, which there are 9 of.

**Implementation:**

I wrote a little Java program with a basic implementation. For 60000 to 100000000000 it takes less than a second, for greater numbers (and even in this range), because of the implementation, there would be arithmetic overflow, so the time taken cannot really be trusted (except that, I hope, it should only take longer (for this range), not shorter).

```
final static long[] tenPowers = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000,
  10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000l, 100000000000l,
  1000000000000l, 10000000000000l, 100000000000000l, 1000000000000000l,
  10000000000000000l, 100000000000000000l, 1000000000000000000l};

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
  System.out.println("Count = "+selfProductCountRange(60000, 100000000000l));
}

static long selfProductCountRange(long s, long f)
{
  start = s;
  finish = f;
  long count = 0;
  for (len = 1; ; len++)
  {
     long temp = selfProductCount(0, 0);
     if (temp == -1)
        break;
     count += temp;
  }
  return count;
}

static long selfProduct(long num)
{
  // pretend 0s are 1s for simplicity in the rest of the code
  long selfProduct = num;
  while (num > 0)
  {
     selfProduct *= Math.max(num % 10, 1);
     num /= 10;
  }
  return selfProduct;
}

static long start, finish;
static int len;

static long selfProductCount(long prefix, int prefixLen)
{
  long max = selfProduct((prefix+1) * tenPowers[len - prefixLen] - 1);
  // overflow hack
  if (max < 0)
     max = finish+1;
  if (max < start)
     return 0;
  long min;
  if (prefixLen != 0)
     min = selfProduct(prefix * tenPowers[len - prefixLen]);
  else
     min = selfProduct(tenPowers[len-1]);
  if (min > finish)
     return -1;
  if (max <= finish && min >= start)
     return getPossibilities(prefixLen);
  long val = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
     long temp = selfProductCount(prefix*10+i, prefixLen+1);
     if (temp == -1)
        break;
     val += temp;
  }
  return val;
}

static long getPossibilities(int prefixLen)
{
  return (long)Math.pow(9, len-prefixLen);
}
```

Comment: I think that your approach is wrong. If you find that max(3,3) is bigger than the upper bound, that doesn't mean that the number like 411 are not in the range. Also you just check for 3-digits numbers

Comment: @Stefan4024 `max(3,3)` is the max for 3 digit numbers starting with 3. Regardless of what happens there (unless `min(3,3)` > finish of range, which is an early stop condition), we'll still process 3 digit numbers starting with 4 (which would include 411). It was a partial example (starting from 1 digit). I changed it to a complete example.

Comment: very thoughtful and helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

So we say the product is formed by `digits` and the `number`.

Just enumerate the digits() and check every permutation(which form the number), see if it's in the range.

An obvious pruning is when the product of the digits and the smallest permutation is larger than the upperbound, you return.

I think it would be fast enough for 32bit integers.

Comment: Checking every permutation can be a big problem, because there are many of them

Comment: @Stefan4024 you should see that the product increases REALLY fast, why don't try write one and see the time it takes